# Tweet using TweetComposer in Android

Tags: android, twitter, fabric.io

I am using TweetComposer for posting a tweet  from my Android app.
Code Snippet:

```
Uri uri= Uri.parse(path);

TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
.text("My First Post")
.image(uri);
builder.show();
```

Here path is local path to the image stored in device's SDcard.
I am sure m pretty much doing it right but still this is not posting the image . Can someone help in figuring out what Am I doing wrong?

I get a message "Unable to load image" when test it on my device having native twitter app.

Answer (score 0):

i was also struck in the same issue assuming you are using twitter4j, try this method

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```